# Python Shelve changing value of element of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, shelve

This one has me stumped so I thought I would challenge others.
I am trying to change one element of a dictionary in a shelve and it is being stubborn.

Here is a demo:

```
db = shelve.open('/tmp/somefile','c')
db['bob'] = {'shoesize':42, 'gender':'m'}
db['bob']
{'shoesize': 42, 'gender': 'm'}
db['bob']['gender'] = 'u'
db['bob']
{'shoesize': 42, 'gender': 'm'}
db['bob'] = {'shoesize': 42, 'gender': 'u'}
db['bob']
{'shoesize': 42, 'gender': 'u'}
```

This is happening on Python 3.6.1 on a RHEL 7 host.
Having upgraded from an earlier RHEL and Python 2 I understand that the underlying libraries have more to do with how shelves function but this is a bit of weird one.

Appologies to 'bob'

Comment: what is `db`?..

Answer (score 1):

From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.open) for `shelf`,

> Because of Python semantics, a shelf cannot know when a mutable persistent-dictionary entry is modified. By default modified objects are written only when assigned to the shelf

Your first try, `db['bob']['gender'] = 'u'`, doesn't work since it's not an assignment to the shelf itself (it's an assignment to the `dict` `db['bob']['gender']`). Your second try does work since it is assignment to a key of the shelf  itself. The [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#example) in the docs will further hammer in this point.

If you were to open with `writeback=True`, you would be able to code normally. However, as the docs note "it would also consume more memory and make the d.close() operation slower."